# Transform docker-compose.yml to docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new in docker and I don't understand how to transform this docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html:ro"
      - "./:/var/log/php"
```

into a simple docker command in one line (if possible).

I've tried this:

`docker build -t mstp2html --mount source=./,target=/var/www/html,ro --mount source=./,target=/var/log/php -f- .`

and this:

`docker run --name mstp2html --mount source=./,target=/var/www/html,ro --mount source=./,target=/var/log/php ./Dockerfile`

but they don't work. What am I missing?

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: While you're using `docker-compose up -d`, in fact it is first doing `docker build ...` and then `docker run -d ...`. So Is that necessary for you to run both `docker build` and `docker run`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two concepts:

- build: the stage in which the docker image is created, but it does not have relation on how it will run
- run: the stage in which you run a docker container based on an existing docker image. In this stage, you can define options such as volumes.

In order for your example to work, you would need to split that into two stages:

1. Build the docker image:

```
docker build -t mstp2html_image .
```

2. Run a container from the image and mount the volumes you want to:

```
docker run --name mstp2html --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/var/www/html,ro --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/var/log/php mstp2html_image
```

Comment: The first command is ok, the second make an error : `docker: Error response from daemon: create ./: "./" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.`

Comment: Got it. The `./` does not work properly. Probably this will work: `docker run --name mstp2html --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/var/www/html,ro --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/var/log/php mstp2html_image`

We have to specify that we're mounting with type `bind`, and the source we can set as `($pwd)` which will give us the current directory.